# How to notify session about data change. Async communictation

Tags: google-app-engine

I have logged clients logged into my GAE based app, waiting for some information (GWT app if it makes any difference).
I have also servlet receiving REST data, saving it to datastore. Information is addressed to the particular client.
My goal is to pass a notification from the receiving servlet to the user session's servlet.
My time limit for data passing is 60s, 1k users/day, 1h for single browser session, 5 notifications per session.

I've considered following scenarios:

**User client request data every 60s, then query datastore for new data.**

This approach is simply bad - huge waste of datastore power (1000*60*n of datastore read operations a day), big consumption of processor time and big memory footprint.

**Using memcache for passing notifications**

Receiver puts notification into memcache, the client checks it, in case of success reads datastore.
All would be ok, with one exception - docs says "you can't trust the memcache", so if there is nothing in the memcache I have to also check datastore. In the effect I have a more complicated solution, with higher memory/processor footprint.

**Queues**

Almost good solution - I just need to put message into pipe, read it on the another side. In this particular case I have to create 1k queues a day what is far beyond the quota, or use tags in queues, when docs says "Experimental, can change in future etc." Using "experimental" service as the vital part of my application doesn't make me happy.

**Channels**

A bit tricky solutions. Browser opens channel on connection, on incoming data the receiver servlet just puts notification into channel, the notified web client calls it's own servlet for refresh data from datastore.
What I dislike in this approach is communication line - the servlet-servlet notification through a web client is probably not the best what can be done.

Have you any better ideas for pass notification from one servlet to the another in GAE cloud?

Comment: don't think you can use the channel API for server--server comms as it's javascript based on the client side in any case.

Comment: Yes, I know. Channel API can be used to servlet-client-servlet communixation, just inform the client, that there is something new to pool, then client calls it's own servlet, reads datastore etc. I clarified my question (I hope).

Comment: I'm from the python side of things, but depending on the size of the message could you not use URLFETCH or similar to pass on the fact the is a new message (or item in the datastore) from one server to another?

Comment: This is not server-server this is session-session communication. Problem is, that different servlets can be allocated on different (and unknown) number of physical machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old problem: you can either do polling or pushing:

1. Polling: this is what you do in 1&2 above. Id propose you merge the two: use memcache and put appropriate object in memcache even if user does not have new data, in this case you can cover all three situations (1. no data ay all, 2. no new data, 3. new data), while still using memcache to minimize cost.
2. Pushing data - this is a preferred way as it minimizes cost and immediatelly notifies users of new data. Use Channel API - here is a GWT wrapper: [`gwt-gae-channel`](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-channel/).